# program stops running in the middle of its processing when i use the copied exe

Tags: c#, winforms, exe

My program run fine when i open the exe in output directory of C# Application but when i copied exe and exe.config file to Desktop and run it, program stops in the middle.

1- I am using Background worker.

2- I am reading a string from appconfig just after     **InitializeComponent();** in Form Constructor

3-Cross Thread Processing is not allowed. and i have checked there is no such exception.

4- i have added many dll's in reference.

Point where it stops executing is shown in the code in comments.

```
  private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        DrawImages(0, 222, 145);
        // Line below executes and label is changed
       //SetLabelText("Creating Movie Here"); 
        CreateMovieFromImages();
      .
      .
      .
    }
```

and the code of  **CreateMovieFromImages()** is

```
    private void CreateMovieFromImages()
    {


     //Line below this point never execute and no message box displays nor any label is changed.
        MessageBox.Show("OK");

        try
        {
            SetLabelText("Creating Movie");
            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
            {
                ImagesUrls.Add(outputDirectory+ "//Tempe" + i + ".bmp");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            throw new Exception(e.Message);
        }
        int width = 1254;
        int height = 1000;
        var framRate = 5;
        try
        {
            using (var vFWriter = new VideoFileWriter())
            {
                vFWriter.Open(outputDirectory + "//TemperaryVideo.wmv", width, height, framRate, VideoCodec.WMV2);
                foreach (var i in ImagesUrls)
                {
                    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(i);
                    SetLabelText("Writing Image" + i + "\n");
                    var bmpReduced = ReduceBitmap(bmp, width, height);
                    vFWriter.WriteVideoFrame(bmpReduced);
                }
                vFWriter.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

I have never tried to run exe like this before so,it is my First time . Maybe i need someother thing to run exe like this .
Exe works fine when it is in output directory of VS Solution.

Thanks a lot for reading my all Question .kindly help me  :)

Comment: @clcto yes it works ..That is the answer

Comment: Mark it then as the answer so this can get closed. If you insert new references, always remember to get them with the app. Other way after releasing would be to bind the dll files to the exe itself. That would bring it back to a standalone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the whole output directory, not just the executable. It depends on the other .dll files that you have added as a reference.